# Sort nvarchar column in SQL Server which consists of alphanumeric

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone suggest how to sort a `nvarchar` column with this sample data:

```
Month     ExpectedResult
------    ----------------
Aug15      Aug15 
Nov15      Oct15
Oct15      Nov15
Sept16     Sept16
```

Comment: You shouldn't store dates/times and related formats as string. That's the first problem here. If you would have stored it as date, for instance, you could just sort it automatically. Now you will need a complicated (and slow) process to convert this string to a sortable value.

Comment: Hey!!Thanks for ur reply... But Thats how the master data is .. Now i need to sort it.. I tried with Convert n cast ..but its not working. Could u help me with this ??

Comment: use substring to get month and year. Cast year to int and use case to convert month name to month number.

Comment: You could try to cast it to a real date (just take the first of the month mentioned), or even try to modify it as a string. If you just replace `Jan` with `01` etc, then you got a string that can be sorted. If your days can have 1 digit (not clear from your example), then you may have to insert a `0` at the third position before sorting. Anyway, it will be slow and cumbersome. In my experience master data can be modified too, and it can be very worthwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use order by CONVERT(datetime,'01'+Mon).

It is working fine for me, I have used the below query:

**select Mon from (select 'Aug15' Mon
union
select 'Nov15' 
union
select 'Oct15'
union
select 'Sep16')as a order by CONVERT(datetime,'01'+Mon);**

Comment: yes, Actually the column was in MonYY format(i.e. Aug15), to change this string to date format i added '01' to the string so Aug15 becomes 01Aug15, and then I changed this string to datetime using convert function.